# Multi threading issue with final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

Tags: java, android, multithreading, firebase, okhttp

I am trying to send the token to my database. However my database does not receive any token. I found out that the final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient() is having threading issues. How to fix this? I am using the latest okhttp3 and okio jar file.

MyfirebaseInstanceIDService.java

```
package ******;

import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;

import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.FormBody;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;

public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    private static final String TAG =   
        MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        sendToken(token);
    }

    private void sendToken(String token) {
        final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder()
                .add("token",token)
                .build();

        final okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
                .url("******")
                .post(body)
                .build();

        final Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    client.newCall(request).execute();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

Stacktrace

```
01-26 05:16:09.564: W/GLSUser(2025): [AppCertManager] IOException while
```

requesting key: 
   01-26 05:16:09.564: W/GLSUser(2025): java.io.IOException: Invalid device key
    response.
   01-26 05:16:09.564: W/GLSUser(2025):     at

```
eka.a(:com.google.android.gms:271)
01-26 05:16:09.564: W/GLSUser(2025):        
eka.a(:com.google.android.gms:4236)
01-26 05:16:09.564: W/GLSUser(2025): at ejz.a(:com.google.android.gms:46)
01-26 05:16:09.564: W/GLSUser(2025): at ejt.a(:com.google.android.gms:53)
01-26 05:16:09.564: W/GLSUser(2025): at ejs.a(:com.google.android.gms:111)
01-26 05:16:09.564: W/GLSUser(2025):at                                                                                                  com.google.android.gms.auth.account.be.
legacy.AuthCronChimeraService.b
(:com.google.android.gms:4052)
01-26 05:16:09.564: W/GLSUser(2025):atdup.call(:com.google.android.gms:2043)
01-26 05:16:09.564: W/GLSUser(2025):a      
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

01-26 05:16:09.564: W/GLSUser(2025):at kmo.run(:com.google.android.gms:450)
   01-26 05:16:09.564: W/GLSUser(2025):at                                                                  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
   01-26 05:16:09.564: W/GLSUser(2025):at                                                          java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor  $Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
   01-26 05:16:09.564: W/GLSUser(2025):at kqt.run(:com.google.android.gms:17)
   01-26 05:16:09.564: W/GLSUser(2025):at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
   01-26 05:16:09.572: W/ContentTaskController(2025): Invalid newTask was
   provided to startTracking.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, add some logging to get a better idea what is going on. For example, are you ever getting the token from Firebase? I suspect not.

Secondly, don't create your own Thread instance to make asynchronous calls with `okhttp`, check `out.enqueue(..callback..)` [see [okhttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes). Much less hassle, all the difficult edge cases handled for you.

However, in this particular case I'd suggest creating a separate IntentService to send your Firebase token to your server. This decouples call duration, error handling and so on from the system call to `onTokenRefresh()`. Inside your IntentService `onHandleIntent()` you can then make a synchronous call using `okhttp`. Keeps everything nice and simple.